# Accessing json key associated value

Tags: json, ruby

This is my json file, and I would want to retrieve the value present in the key `title` that is under a list. i.e `LiveHealth` , `OneMedical` and `visit guardian`

```
    {
  "data": {
    "perksAndWellBeing": [
      {
        "title": "Physical Wellbeing",
        "perks": [
          {
            "id": "a3N33000EAO",
            "logo": "https:933000001P3v1AAC-1.png",
            "logoLarge": "https:\33000001P3v6AAC-1.png",
            "title": "LiveHealth Online",

          },
          {
            "id": "a3N3300AO",
            "logo": "https:\/\-attachments\/06933000001P3uwAAC-1.png",
            "logoLarge": "https:/hments\/06933000001P3umAAC-1.png",
            "title": "One Medical",

          },
          {
            "id": "a3N3300EA4",
            "logo": "https:\/\/s33000001P3vQAAS-1.png",
            "logoLarge": "https:\/06933000001P3vVAAS-1.png",
            "title": "Access To Top Specialists",

          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Emotional Wellbeing",
        "perks": [
          {
            "id": null,
            "logo": "https:\/\/s00001P3vpAAC-1.png",
            "logoLarge": "https:\/\/attachmeOAAS-1.png",
            "title": "Visit Guardian EAP",

          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Financial Wellbeing",
        "perks": [
          {
            "id": "a3N3300HEA4",
            "logo": "https:\/\/sg",
            "logoLarge": "https:\/SAAS-1.png",
            "title": "Track your finances and get free access to financial advice",

          },
          {
            "id": "a3N33000EA4",
            "logo": "https:\/\/s",
            "logoLarge": "https:\/\/",
            "title": "Better student loan refinancing, mortgages, and personal loans",

          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "Perks",
        "perks": [
          {
            "id": "a3N3300LxEAO",
            "logo": "https:\/\",
            "logoLarge": "https:\/,
            "title": "Anthem Programs",

          },
          {
            "id": "a3N3300000EA4",
            "logo": "https:\",
            "logoLarge": "https:\",
            "title": "Receive gym discounts, travel discounts, and more",

          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Currently, I am able to retrieve the title's that has value as `Physical wellbeing` and `Emotional wellbeing` but I am not able to access the values in the list.

```
perkswellbeing = JSON.parse(perks)
  #puts perkswellbeing
  puts "*********************"
  g = JSON.parse(perks)
  result1 = g["data"]["perksAndWellBeing"].select {|g1| g1['title']}
  result1.each do |rest1|
    $perks = rest1['title']
    puts $perks
```

Not sure what Am I missing! Could anyone please help me out.

Comment: I think there's a problem with your JSON object.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Let me recheck, give me a min

Comment: I have updated the json @SebastiánPalma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
json = JSON.parse(perks)
perksAWB = json["data"]["perksAndWellBeing"] # array

perks = perksAWB.map do |pawb|
  pawb["perks"].map { |p| p["title"] } 
end # array of titles

puts perks.inspect  # printing, or:
```

To print everything without brackets, use `flatten`:

```
perks.flatten.each(&method(:puts))
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, Could you please tell me, how do I remove the `[ ]` from the result? I do not want to have the results inside the square brackets. I guess the `.map` returns the results inside the brackets?

Comment: I would want these results to be printed without the brackets

`[["LiveHealth Online", "One Medical", "Access To Top Specialists"], ["Visit Guardian EAP"], ["Track your finances and get free access to financial advice", "Better student loan refinancing, mortgages, and personal loans"], ["Anthem Programs", "Receive gym discounts, travel discounts, and more"]]
`

Comment: I have updated the answer: use `flatten` on the result.

Comment: Perfect! Still it was printing in one bracket, but removed it with `puts perks.flatten.each(&method(:puts)).join(',')` Thanks a lot

Comment: I am not sure as to why the code above, is printing the values twice? 
`Visit Guardian EAP
      Track your finances and get free access to financial advice
      Better student loan refinancing, mortgages, and personal loans
      Anthem Programs
      Receive gym discounts, travel discounts, and more
      [ "Track your finances and get free access to financial advice", "Better student loan refinancing, mortgages, and personal loans", "Anthem Programs", "Receive gym discounts, travel discounts, and more"]`

It prints each one by one and everything once in an array, above.

Comment: `puts perks.join(', ')` to print a string of values, concatenated with commas. Do not try to copy-paste the code, understand what it does.

Comment: You are right ! After understanding the logic in your code, I could get this work my way writing this

`json = JSON.parse(perks)
  perksAWB = json['data']['perksAndWellBeing'].each do |pawb|
    perkplans = pawb['perks'].each do |actualperk|
      puts actualperk['title']`

ahh! Its all about iterating the nested until you get your key. Damn! I was just being reactive